# PostgreSQL - removing trailing comma before WHERE from query string

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I have an API that takes a PATCH request with one or more parameters and build a query string that looks like this

```
UPDATE ${table} SET ${param1}${param2}${param3} WHERE id=${id}
```

problem is if I place commas inside params or in the final query, a request with a single parameter breaks the query

```
UPDATE ${table} SET ${param1}, WHERE id=${id}
```

or

```
UPDATE ${table} SET ${param1},, WHERE id=${id}
```

how do I remove commas before WHERE?

Comment: Which  language do you use for your API ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze node.js

Answer (score 0):

You could join all the params together, but make sure that the input is sanitized for sql injection. Assuming they're already in a list like

```
params = [param1, param2, param3];
paramsStr = params.join(", ");
```

example:

```
["abc='def'", "xyz=123"].join(',')
#outputs:
'abc=\'def\',xyz=123'
```

And then use the `paramsStr` in your query template. With this simple trick you avoid having to deal with trailing / leading commas

```
UPDATE ${table} SET ${paramsStr} WHERE id=${id}
```